# Sencha CMD problem after macOS Monterrey update

Tags: java, macos, extjs, sencha-cmd

## Problem

After update my macOS to Monterrey (12.0.1),  I'm with a big problem to start my local projects with ExtJS.

When I execute:

```
sencha app watch
```

Get the error:

```
Sencha Cmd v7.5.0.5
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff813dcb6f2, pid=18621, tid=0x000000000000a707
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_242-b08) (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b08 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x16f2]  _platform_strlen+0x12
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# [my app folder]/hs_err_pid18621.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
/Users/kellerkichel/bin/Sencha/Cmd/sencha: line 167: 18621 Abort trap: 6           $BASEDIR/$VER/sencha "$@"
```

The funny thing is... if run again... the same command (`sencha app watch`), the error change:

```
2021-12-06 22:10:28.229 java[17909:173895] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff813efae5b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff813c5bb9d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007ff814c9126d -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 295
    3   Foundation                          0x00007ff814c9ff2f +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 153
    4   Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x00000001218897a9 wuusgJAD + 553
    5   Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x0000000121874319 pGgFelzv + 9
    6   Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x0000000121888ab2 MKNXgAzM + 562
    7   Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x000000012188795d tyRtaPXr + 61
    8   Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x00000001218877bb ZWwnJFGw + 283
    9   Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x0000000121880dc6 Phdl_SDOTFG + 246
    10  Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x0000000121880e49 Phdl_SDOTF + 25
    11  Update1478821341979869630.dylib     0x000000012186e505 Java_phdl_Phdl_SDOTF + 21
    12  ???                                 0x000000010e0e3407 0x0 + 4530779143
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
/Users/kellerkichel/bin/Sencha/Cmd/sencha: line 167: 17909 Abort trap: 6           $BASEDIR/$VER/sencha "$@"
```

And again (`sencha app watch`)... another one:

```
java(18084,0x7000041c5000) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x6000005f3330
*** Incorrect guard value: 105553126503408
java(18084,0x7000041c5000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
/Users/kellerkichel/bin/Sencha/Cmd/sencha: line 167: 18084 Abort trap: 6           $BASEDIR/$VER/sencha "$@"
```

And after each execution, the error keep alternating between those above...

## Attempts

1 - JAVA
First, I thinked is something with **JAVA** version, so I removed all **JAVA** installed, including **brew** installed versions.

Also removed all references to **JAVA_HOME**, and a fresh install of **JAVA 8** was maked. No sucess... did it again with **JAVA 11**, and **JAVA 17**, without sucess.

Obs. At JAVA 17 the problem changed, but this is because **JAVA 17**  dont have the javascript processor (`javax`) anymore.

2 - SENCHA CMD
After the JAVA, have checked **Sencha cmd**, if has any update or something... my **Sencha cmd** versio is 7.4.0.39, and for my surprise have a new version (7.5.0.5), but also after update still not working.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 26):

After talking with some sencha MVP at discord.... have received the following tip:

> You must delete the following file:
> /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sencha/Cmd/Update/app.properties

After that workaround, the system works again.
I hope these answer can help someone !!

Update!!!

After some mac os updates deleting the app.properties stop working.
So sencha report to add `bypass_lp:true` to the `app.json`

Comment: That worked for me!
Wish I found this earlier today. So many hours down the drain.
Thanks!!!

Comment: That also seems to solve the issue for me. Cheers!

Comment: That solution worked for a few weeks and today the issues are back again.

Comment: Update on Sencha CMD ticket SKDTOOLS-2139: "As per the latest from our Engineering team that in an order to resolve this issue. Please update app.json as below"

"bypass_lp": true

Comment: With MacOS 12.2 the issue came back, which was fixed by deleting the app.properties. Adding bypass_lp helps with that. Thanks Keller... Maybe you can update your answer an also add this information.

Comment: macOS Monterey 12.6 - your decision helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

vi `find . -name "app.json" -print`

after the line

**"framework" : "ext",**

place the line:

**"bypass_lp" : "true",**

Into each file, save the files, and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download JRE 8(support apple sillicon neccessary, ex:zulu/bellsoft), and unzip it.
2. Edit path in "{your_senchacmd_path}/.install4j/inst_jre.cfg" and "{your_senchacmd_path}/.install4j/pref_jre.cfg" to new JRE path.

Reason: Sencha CMD's included JRE is not compiled for the ARM architecture and even with Rosetta 2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).