# ExtJs - How fixing this error when sencha app build

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff817e17572, pid=13762, tid=0x0000000000004d03
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_242-b08) (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b08 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x1572]  _platform_strlen+0x12
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /cores/core or core.13762
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Library/WebServer/Documents/Learning/info-pd/info-pd-fe/hs_err_pid13762.log
[thread 17923 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
zsh: abort      sudo /Users/xxxxxxxx/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.3.0.19/sencha app build
```

and i'm try build, i'm getting other error like this

```
Sencha Cmd v7.3.0.19
[INF] Using GPL version of Ext JS version 7.0.0.168 from /Library/WebServer/Documents/Learning/info-pd/info-pd-fe/ext.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : classic (production environment)
java(14297,0x700002dff000) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x600001cdd390
*** Incorrect guard value: 105553133774736
java(14297,0x700002dff000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      sudo /Users/xxxxxxxx/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.3.0.19/sencha app build
```

Whenever I am trying to execute command: `sencha app build` its failed with this error.
Please help me, how to fixing that?

> Info:
> I'm use ext-7.0.0 GPL version
> and Sencha CMD 7.3.0

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at related questions; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266708.  (Google for "sencha app build crash" or similar.)  You could also reach out to the Sencha devs on discord,

Comment: @StephenC owwh my goood.. yeaah, that worked! Wish I found this earlier today. So many hours down the drain. thank very much..